Explicit & implicit Euler and trapezoid method of ODE solving in Python
I have a question regarding my code. I have to solve an ODE: [y′(t)=(0.5−t)(y(t) + 1), y(0) = 1], numerically (and approximate), using the explicit and implicit Euler as well as the trapezoid method and I used Python for it. To me it looks fine, but when comparing to my classmates results the values differ and none of us know the right answer. Have I implemented the three methods in the right way? The code below is what I tried.
Thank you very much in advance!
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Solver function
def solveIVP(f, tspan, y0, h, solver):
    t = np.arange(tspan[0], tspan[1]+h, h)
    y = np.zeros(len(t))
    y[0] = y0
    
    for n in range(len(t)-1):
        y[n+1] = solver(f, t[n], y[n], h)
    return t, y

# Analytical solution
# Define the function y(t)
def y_function(t):
    return 2 * np.exp(0.5*t - 0.5*t**2) - 1
# Calculate y values for the given range of t
t_values = np.linspace(-1, 2, 100)
y_function_values = y_function(t_values)
    

# Euler method
def explicit_euler(f, tn, yn, h):
    return yn + h * f(tn, yn)

# Implicit Euler method
def implicit_euler(f, tn, yn, h):
    return yn + h * f(tn + h, yn + h * f(tn, yn))

# Trapezoid method
def trapezoid(f, tn, yn, h):
    k1 = f(tn, yn)
    k2 = f(tn + h, yn + h * k1)
    return yn + h / 2 * (k1 + k2)

# Define IVP
def f(t,y):
    return (0.5-t)*(y+1)

tspan = [0, 1]
y0 = 1
h = 0.2

# Solve IVP using explicit Euler method
t, y_e = solveIVP(f, tspan, y0, h, explicit_euler)
# Solve IVP using implicit Euler method
t, y_i = solveIVP(f, tspan, y0, h, implicit_euler)
# Solve IVP using trapezoid method
t, y_t = solveIVP(f, tspan, y0, h, trapezoid)

# Print table of solution values
print("|  t    |  y_e  | ")
print("|:-----:|:-----:|")
for n in range(len(t)):
    print(f"| {t[n]:0.3f} | {y_e[n]:0.3f} |")
print("|---------------|")
print("|  t    |  y_i  | ")
print("|:-----:|:-----:|")
for n in range(len(t)):
    print(f"| {t[n]:0.3f} | {y_i[n]:0.3f} |")
print("|---------------|")
print("|  t    |  y_t  | ")
print("|:-----:|:-----:|")
for n in range(len(t)):
    print(f"| {t[n]:0.3f} | {y_t[n]:0.3f} |")


# Plot solution
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(t_values, y_function_values, "k-", label="Analytical")
plt.plot(t, y_e, "bo-", label="explicit Euler")
plt.plot(t, y_i, "go-", label="implicit Euler")
plt.plot(t, y_t, "ro-", label="trapezoid")
plt.quiver(T, Y, U, V, angles='xy')
plt.xlim(-1, 2)
plt.ylim(-1, 2)
plt.xlabel("$t$", fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel("$y$", fontsize=20)
plt.xticks(fontsize=16)
plt.yticks(fontsize=16)
plt.legend(fontsize=16)
plt.show()


Why do you believe your answer is wrong? Your methods for explicit Euler ("forward Euler") and trapezoid method ("Heun's method") appear correct. Your implicit Euler method isn't implicit Euler ("backward Euler"), because the RHS doesn't depend on y(n+1), so it isn't implicit. An implicit method would usually require iteration, although for your test problem, which is linear in y, you could rearrange to avoid this.

none of the variables on this line are dfined: plt.quiver(T, Y, U, V, angles='xy')...

Speculation on the value differences: If "trapezoidal method" without qualifier is given, it most likely means the implicit method, as the explicit method is more commonly labeled as "Heun's method" or one of "modified/improved Euler". As in the implicit Euler case, the implicit trapezium method requires iteration (simple or some Newton variant) or explicit transformation of the step equation.

Could you collect and display some example results, the last 5 lines or so, of your code vs. some of your compatriots efforts?
